# Is it possible to have phone number starts exactly the same as country code?

Tags: sms

I hope this is the right place to ask this, feel free to redirect me to anywhere else.

As title, here's an example of what I meant.

let's say the country is Switzerland with the country code of 41.

Is 4141xxxxxxx (41xxxxxxx) a possible number in international format? Is there any rules that prevent a number to start  with the exact digit of their corresponding country code?

I tried to look the info up for quite a while but I can't find any info specificlly describing this case. Any help is welcome. (It'll be amazing if the info is cited with source as well so I can have a look too.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not related to Windows Phone. If it is, please explain the relation.

Comment: yeah, I though that might be the case. This is the only forum within the network I found that is related to phone. I also saw a few other SMS related question in here so I took a chance. Thank you for answering it none the less.

Comment: Happy to help. BTW, [Android Enthusiasts](http://android.stackexchange.com) and [Ask Different](http://apple.stackexchange.com) also accept questions about phones (Android and iOS, respectively). But there indeed doesn't seem to be any Stack Exchange site dedicated to telecommunications. If you happen to feel passionate about this subject, you can start a proposal for a new site at [Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/categories/8/technology).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I can see, it is at least theoretically possible for a local phone number to start with the same numbers as the country code. The format of the local numbers is entirely up to each individual country.

For instance, [telephone numbers in Switzerland](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telephone_numbers_in_Switzerland) start with a two-digit national destination code, and one of those destination codes is **41** (Central Switzerland), same as the country code. So it's possible for a Swiss number to begin with **+4141**.

Likewise, Germany (whose country code is 49) has [many area codes beginning with **049**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Area_codes_in_Germany#049.C2.A0.E2.80.93_Emden_and_surroundings), so it's possible for a German number to begin with **+4949** (the zero is omitted from the area code when calling from abroad).